# Can't Get real-time date with Alpha-vantage using python

Tags: python, api, real-time, alpha-vantage

```
import pandas as pd
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries

def AlphaVantage(symbol):
     ts = TimeSeries(key="mykey")
     data = ts.get_intraday(symbol, interval='1min')
     print(str(data[0][max(data[0].keys())]))
AlphaVantage('MSFT')
```

im trying to do a project at my university using alpha vantage however its not showing real time data instead its showing info from 2 days ago and is stuck at 2020-1-31. I looked on another thread about the same problem and it provided the code above and it doesnt seem to give me updated data. Can anyone help me please?
i just want real-time data updated on every api call, please!

Answer (score 2):

You posted this during the weekend, stock exchanges are closed during the weekend, so it will show you what the price was Friday.

---

Additionally, if you want a lighter weight function, use the `get_quote_endpoint` function:

```py
import pandas as pd
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries

def AlphaVantage(symbol):
     ts = TimeSeries(key="mykey")
     data, _ = ts.get_quote_endpoint(symbol)
     print(data)
AlphaVantage('MSFT')
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the intraday function:

```
data = ts.get_intraday(symbol, interval='1min')
```

During the day 1/4/2023 and got 1/3/2023 data.  After the market closed it still returned 1/3 data.  In the evening I finally got the 1/4 data.